# volume of polyhedra which correspond to icosahedral fullerenes

Tags: polyhedra

There is, I believe, a sequence of polyhedra whose shape approaches that of the icosahedron ([they all have twelve pentagonal faces and the rest hexagons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18340/why-are-there-12-pentagons-and-20-hexagons-on-a-soccer-ball)), and starts:

regular dodecahedron (C$_{12}$, dodecahedrane)

truncated icosahedron (C$_{60}$, buckminsterfullerene)

?: (C$_{240}$, buckminsterfullerene)

?: (C$_{540}$, ?)

I am interested in the polyhedra that these molecules are associated with, namely:

- What is the correct name for this sequence of polyhedra? (oeis.org doesn't have any sequences that match "12,60,240,540" at present)

  Is there a formula in the literature for the volume of these polyhedra? (the surface area is not a difficult computation)

Answer (score 2):

The volume of a regular dodecahedron, having 12 congruent regular pentagonal faces each with edge length $a$, is given by the generalized expression $$\bbox[4pt, border: 1px solid blue;]{\color{blue}{V_{\text{dodecahedron}}}=\color{red}{\frac{(15+7\sqrt{5})a^3}{4}}\color{purple}{\approx 7.663118961 \space a^3}}$$ (Note: For derivation & detailed explanation, kindly go through [HCR's formula for platonic solids](https://www.academia.edu/9727820/HCRs_Formula_for_Regular_n-Polyhedron_Mathematical_analysis_of_regular_n-polyhedrons_all_five_platonic_solids_) )

The volume of a truncated icosahedron, having 12 congruent regular pentagonal faces & 20 congruent regular hexagonal faces each with edge length $a$, is given by the generalized expression $$\bbox[4pt, border: 1px solid blue;]{\color{blue}{V_{\text{truncated icosahedron}}}=\color{red}{\frac{(125+43\sqrt{5})a^3}{4}}\color{purple}{\approx55.28773076\space a^3}}$$ (Note: For derivation & detailed explanation, kindly go through [Mathematical analysis of truncated icosahedron by HCR](https://www.academia.edu/9844328/Mathematical_analysis_of_truncated_icosahedron_and_identical_football_Applications_of_HCRs_Theory_of_Polygon_and_HCRs_formula_for_platonic_solids_) )